# Creating msbuild script to build, publish with specified app.config, and update from different locations

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, msbuild, cmd

I have googled everywhere for this solution and cannot find anything!

I want to have a msbuild script to do the following:

1. Build the project solution
2. Publish the built solution with the specified app.config (app.config.debug or app.config.release) to a specified folder (Development or Production)
3. With the specified configuration, know where to check for updates. 
       -if deployment -> check in the sample production folder 
       -if development -> check in the sample development folder

The script currently works but there are two problems...

- I cannot figure out how to have two different installations that check two different places to check for updates.
- I cannot auto increment the revision build. It currently stays at the same build number everytime i use the script.

**My Current script:**

```
msbuild "C:\sample\sample.csproj"
/t:clean
/t:build
/t:publish
/p:Configuration=release
/property:PublishDir="C:\Samplelocation/"
/property:UpdatedEnabled=true
/property:UpdateRequired=true
/property:UpdateUrl="C:\Samplelocation/"
/property:GenerateManifests=true
/property:PublishWizardCompleted=true
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks ahead of time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at MSBuild [Batching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171473(VS.80).aspx).

Here are some links on batching:

- [MSBuild Batching Part 1](http://www.sedodream.com/PermaLink,guid,5f1e0445-ce3d-4052-ba80-42fd19512d42.aspx)
- [MSBuild Batching Part 2](http://www.sedodream.com/PermaLink,guid,b721bc22-c375-4e1e-bcc9-512dd64096bb.aspx)
- [MSBuild Batching Part 3](http://www.sedodream.com/PermaLink,guid,cab57d7f-9d6e-4358-8491-dc033fb3bacc.aspx)
- [MSBuild RE: Enforcing the Build Agent in a Team Build](http://www.sedodream.com/PermaLink,guid,096a2e3f-fcff-4715-8d00-73d8f2491a13.aspx)

Comment: Thank you, Sayed. While not the exact answer, the links provided look more than useful. :)

Comment: I believe the first link is dead, and the following links are to your personal blog. It would be nice if you elaborated so this would be a more useful answer.

Comment: Marked down as none of the links have any information regarding the question.

Comment: Just curious if there is any update for VS2022 built apps?