# msbuild publish with different app.config

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-task

I'm currently writing an msbuild script to publish a solution, which is all fine but i want to use a different app.config depending on what configuration is selected.

- i've seen people talk about transforms, but this natively only works for web.config (yes you can do it for app.config with a little hacking but doesn't seem to work for the publish task on msbuild)
- [Creating msbuild script to build, publish with specified app.config, and update from different locations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1375134/creating-msbuild-script-to-build-publish-with-specified-app-config-and-update-f)
  i've also seen this post but it doesn't actually answer this specific question (After reading the links).

currently my build script looks like:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <ProjectFile>.\BarcodeScannerApp\BarcodeScannerApp.csproj</ProjectFile>
    <SolutionFile>.\BarcodeScannerApp.sln</SolutionFile>        
    <PublishLoc>http://publishlocation.com</PublishLoc>
    <Configuration>release</Configuration>
    <GenerateManifests>false</GenerateManifests>
    <BootstrapperEnabled>true</BootstrapperEnabled>
    <ApplicationVersion>1.0.0.*</ApplicationVersion>
    <UpdateEnabled>true</UpdateEnabled>
    <UpdateMode>Foreground</UpdateMode>
    <UpdateUrl>http://backoffice-dev/</UpdateUrl>
</PropertyGroup>

<Target Name="PublishApp">      

    <MSBuild Projects="$(SolutionFile)" 
             Targets="Publish"               
             Properties="PublishUrl=$(PublishLoc);
             Configuration=$(Configuration);
             GenerateManifests=$(GenerateManifests);
             BootstrapperEnabled=$(BootstrapperEnabled);
             ApplicationVersion=$(ApplicationVersion);
             UpdateEnabled=$(UpdateEnabled);
             UpdateMode=$(UpdateMode);
             UpdateUrl=$(UpdateUrl)"
    />

</Target>
```

currently when this script is run, it generates a file BarcodeScannerApp.exe.config which is a copy of the app.config i have in the solution. i want to use a different config file depending on what different configuration i set up (Debug / Release).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As first you need to define properties which references an `app.config` path for all config files like:

```
<DebugConfig>...</DebugConfig>
<ReleaseConfig>...</ReleaseConfig>
<TargetConfigPath>...</TargetConfigPath>
```

And then using `WHEN` select an appropriate one and rewrite into the target directory

```
<When Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='DEBUG'">
     ...
</When>

<When Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='RELEASE'">
     ...
</When>
```

You can rewrite files before executing `PublishApp` targetby introducing new target and create target dependency.

Comment: Are you suggesting I edit the app.config? depending on the Configuration setting? i.e.   1) check configuration (debug or release) 2) edit app.config with new variables? 3) run the Publish task?

Comment: Not edit, copy right one to the output folder so PublishApp task will pickup file which you've just copied. So you just copy from debugConfig.config or releaseCOnfig.config to /rightpath/app.config